# Data loss in conversion of documents from .odt to .doc

Tags: ms-word, openoffice-writer

I have a plugin developed for both MS word and Open Office.

Using the open office plugin it is possible to add a set of Marked references (using XNamed) the xml in content.xml for this mark is:

```
-<text:p text:style-name="Standard">
<text:reference-mark-start text:name="abc"/>hello
<text:reference-mark-end text:name="abc"/>
</text:p>
```

when I save this document as .doc or .docx and open it in MS word, the mark reference is lost and only plain text (hello) appears. I want to be able to preserve some information like "abc" here.

Is there a way I can programatically change the xml while open office is converting it to doc format, or while ms word is opening the converted document?

Is there a way(in ms word) to "Realize" that the document being opened was created or edited using open office?

I've used C# interop to develop the word plugin and java UNO for open office.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up providing a "compatibility mode" button in my plugins,for modifying the document before saving and after opening...couldnt find a better solution.